# Why Maven ear package uses project's old jar version despite war subprojects contains latest jar version?

Tags: java, maven, jar, war, ear

I have a maven project with 4 subprojects, let's say the following structure:

```
  Main 
   |- core (jar)
   |- webapp1 (war)
   |- webapp2 (war)
   |- webapp3 (war)
```

The three webapp subprojects depends on core subproproject. So the poms are like:

Main (pom.xml):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyArtifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
  </repositories>

  <modules>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>webapp1</module>
    <module>webapp2</module>
    <module>webapp3</module>
  </modules> 
   ...
</project>
```

Core (pom.xml):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
...
</project>
```

And web app poms are like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>webapp1</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0-A1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

Everything worked fine during months when i execute 'mvn package' on the project's root folder and deploy the wars being generated.

But now i want to deploy an Ear instead of separate War files so i added a subproject called earproject. With the following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>earproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.10.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <finalName>EarName</finalName>
              <version>5</version>
              <generatedDescriptorLocation>${basedir}/src/main/applicatio/META-INF</generatedDescriptorLocation>
          <modules>
              <webModule>
                  <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
                  <artifactId>webapp1</artifactId>
                  <bundleFileName>webapp1.war</bundleFileName>
                  <contextRoot>/webapp1</contextRoot>
              </webModule>
              <webModule>
                  <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
                  <artifactId>webapp2</artifactId>
                  <bundleFileName>webapp2.war</bundleFileName>
                  <contextRoot>/webapp2</contextRoot>
              </webModule>
              <webModule>
                  <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
                  <artifactId>webapp3</artifactId>
                  <bundleFileName>webapp3.war</bundleFileName>
                  <contextRoot>/webapp3</contextRoot>
              </webModule>
          </modules>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>webapp1</artifactId>
      <type>war</type>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>webapp2</artifactId>
      <type>war</type>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>webapp3</artifactId>
      <type>war</type>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Whith this configuration when i run 'mvn clean' and 'mvn package' the ear file is generated but the war files inside the ear file contains an invalid old version of the core.jar. 
If i check target directories on webapp projects the War files has a right core.jar version. It seems like EAR packaging uses an old version of the jar that is in my mvn repository, but i don't know why, because on the separate war files maven puts the recently created core.jar.

Why is this happening? Do i need to specify anything more on earproject's pom.xml?

Comment: At the root of the ear project try the command `mvn dependency:tree` and `mvn help:effective-pom` which would help you to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you are describing can be solved easily. In appearance Maven ear plugin is getting the core jar file from the repository instead of the new compiled one. I don't know the reason of this plugin's behaviour but I found this issue long time ago.

You should install your jar libraries in the local repository by using the following command

```
mvn clean install
```

instead of

```
mvn package
```

which only generates the artifacts

Comment: So, i need to install the jar before packaging with EAR plugin. Ok, i'll try. Thanks

Comment: Ok, that worked. But is a really strange behaviour of the EAR plugin compared to WAR plugin thar uses the jar being generated, not the ones from the repository.

Comment: Thats because theres no point in installing the war file to the repository. WAR files are just needed to be deployed to the server and `mvn package` is enough to generate the war file in the target folder.